# Set ImageView visible/invisible from activity's adapter

Tags: android, listview, imageview

I have an activity with a listview over an imageview (sort of a background for the list view). When the arraylist of the activity's adapter is empty, I want to set the imageview visible, and when there is one or more object(s) on my arraylist I want to set the imageview invisible.

Whenever I change the arraylist, I am calling this from the adapter:

```
((MainActivity)context).checkForLogo();
```

and the checkForLogo method on MainActivity:

```
public void checkForLogo()
{
    ImageView logoView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageViewLogo);
    if (adapter.getCount() == 0)
        logoView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    else
        logoView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

I am getting NullPointerException. When I set visibility directly from the activity then it works (example from onCreate). But that won't work for my problem since I need to do it every time the adapter's arraylist is modified.

Comment: adapter or logoView may be null. try to debug it. you'll find the solution.

Comment: Declaring it static (the imageview) and accessing from the adapter like this - MainActivity.logoView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); worked as Zhenxiao Hao suggested.

Comment: I don't think it is a good solution.

Comment: I'll think more on the previous solution if I can spot what is wrong but for now that is the one solution that worked so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to declare your `logoView` global and initialize it inside `onCreate`

Comment: Worked perfectly. Sorry I can't upvote because of low reputation.

Comment: Thanks, I'll think a bit more on this because I still don't get why it didn't work the old way.